# C# Dictionary Deserialization

Tags: c#, serialization, xna

I have a serializable class called tileSet, which contains a dictionary(ushort,Tile). The Tile class in said dictionary is also serializable, and contains a dictionary(string,Rectangle[]) within it.

The issue is when I go to deserialize an instance of tileSet, while in the Deserialization Constructor of Tile, the tile's dictionary(string,Rectangle[]) remains with count=0, despite being set using SerializationInfo.GetValue.

The bizzare part is, once we leave the deserialization constructor of Tile, and tileSet is fully deserialized; we see that the Tile's dictionary(string,Rectangle[]) is now populated correctly.

Does any one have an explanation for this delay? (Watered down code below)

TileSet Deserialization:

```
Stream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);
BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

// The following line will place us in Tile's 
// Deserialization constructor below
TileSet tileSet = (TileSet)bFormatter.Deserialize(stream);

// If debugging, by this point tileSet's, Tile's dictionary is 
// now properly set with a count of 0.
stream.Close();
```

Tile Deserialization Constructor:

```
//Deserialization Constructor
public Tile(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext sContext)
{
    mAnimations = (Dictionary<string, Rectangle[]>)
                    info.GetValue("animations", 
                                  typeof(Dictionary<string, Rectangle[]>));
    mPaused = false;
    mName = (string)info.GetValue("name", typeof(string));
    mWalkable = (bool)info.GetValue("walkable", typeof(bool));
    mInstanced = (bool)info.GetValue("instanced", typeof(bool));

    setCurrentState((string)info.GetValue("currentState", typeof(string)));
    //By this point mAnimations is not properly set but has a count=0
}
```

Comment: If you can avoid serializing a dictionary, you'll save yourself many headaches down the road. Instead serialize an array of KeyValuePairs and recreate the dictionary during deserialization.

Comment: Is `mAnimations` a field, a non-virtual property, or a virtual property?

Comment: @Osiris seconded. Dictionary serialization is haphazard. Lists or arrays are far easier to work with.

Comment: Meh. The serialisation code for dictionary does much the same too. Unless I had to promise future backwards compatibility with the serialisation, I'd serialise the dictionary until it actually did cause a problem, write the dozen lines of code to change it after.

Comment: Looks like I overlooked the onDeserialization() Method. However, I switched to serializing as a list.

Comment: Couldn't you just create an XElement for the Key and an XAttribute for the Value to end up with a simple XML representation?

Comment: If you're happy with my answer, you should mark it as accepted (even if you did switch to a list)

Answer (score 0):

You can force the dictionary to perform it's OnDeserialization by doing this in your ondeserialize method/ deserialize constructor.

```
mAnimations = (Dictionary<string, Rectangle[]>)  
    info.GetValue("animations",
        typeof(Dictionary<string, Rectangle[]>));  
mAnimations.OnDeserialize(this);
```